# DownloadManager vs. Play Store Expansion File

Tags: android

I have an app which requires a 30MB database file to function. Currently, this is downloaded (as a 10MB zip file) on first run.  I'm considering switching to using a Google Play Store Expansion File.

Apart from the obvious Expansion File dependency on downloading the app from the Google Play Store, what are the other pros and cons?

For example, I'm thinking of potential (Google) server issues when accessing from within China.

EDIT: The app already has hundreds of thousands of active installs using the current 1MB APK. If I place the zip file in assets, then the APK will suddenly increases to 11MB.  I'm concerned this will potentially cause problems for users with low storage space available.  Also the database is periodically updated (i.e. fresh download of latest zip file) so it seems a little wasteful.

Comment: If it is only `30MB` you can place it in your apk... :)

Comment: I have edited the question to explain concerns about bundling the zip in the APK.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you implement both, you won't ever be able to distribute over non-Google Android app stores. There are many: Amazon, Nook Store, Appia, to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few advantages I can think of:
You don't need to care about hosting (you don't need to pay for servers / bandwidth)
I would say the general availability of the files is also better if they are on google's servers (they have redundant servers all around the world, while you usually only have one or two servers)
The user can usually use the program as soon as the market download is finished (no additional waiting on first start) (except for 'some cases' as google states: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html )

And by the way, google states that the limit for 'normal' apks is now 50MB so you might not need the expansion files after all.

Answer (score 0):

For an asset of 10MB, I don't see much advantage in using an Expansion File over bundling the asset in the APK.  Combined with the likelihood that you will (at some point) be distributing the app via non-Play Store means (e.g. you may just want to send the APK to someone to test) you might as well disregard the Expansion File option.

If you need to update the database then you can either just release a new APK (with updated zip asset) or implement download functionality.  The best approach probably depends on how often the database needs to be updated. Do you update the APK update more often than the database?

The added complexity with DownloadManager is that it's only available from Gingerbread upwards.  Going forward, this will become less of an issue, of course.

Bottom line: bundle the zip as an asset and only implement DownloadManager if/when you really need to.

Not sure about the risks of updating an APK from 1MB to 11MB (e.g. users not having enough storage). Anyone have any experience of this?